# Programmatically setting tags (cq:tags) in a required node under etc/tags

Tags: aem, jcr

I am trying to set `cq:tags` under `etc/tags/example/ABC`
But when the code runs, new tags are created under a `/default/` directory:

`etc/tags/default/etc/tags/example/ABC`

Comment: What version of AEM are you using? Also, when you say 'when the code run', which code are you referring to? AEM code or custom code? If custom, is it possible to get some details on it?

Answer (score 1):

AEM tags are always grouped into **namespaces**. When setting your tag, your are not specifying a namespace so AEM is using the `default` namespace.

You should use the following format: `namespace:your/tag` so in your case it would be `example:ABC`.

More information:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/tag_admin.html#Creating Tags and Namespaces